# How can you interpert the percent of variance explained by additional values with Nagelkerke's r^2

Tags: generalized-linear-model, variance, poisson-regression, nested-data

I have Nagelkerke's R^2 for two Poisson regression models, model A contains several predictors while model B contains all the predictors of A plus a couple extra. Would it be correct to say that the proportion of variance explained in B beyond what is explained in A is equal to $1-(1-R^2_B)/(1-R^2_A)$ based on property iv of [this paper](http://www.cesarzamudio.com/uploads/1/7/9/1/17916581/nagelkerke_n.j.d._1991_-_a_note_on_a_general_definition_of_the_coefficient_of_determination.pdf)? In addition, is Nagelkerke's R^2 appropriate for all GLM models or just logistic regression?